# Is it possible to implement minimally logged reads from a disk table

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016

My code uses a table that links SQL Server SPIDs with CompanyIDs.  For example

```
Spid|CompanyID
1   | 123
2   | 412
```

Every time a request reaches the database, the request first checks this table to get the current user's company ID, and if there isn't one, it inserts it.

Naturally, this is a very high traffic table.  My current implementation is using a non-durable in memory table using SQL Server 2016 in memory OLTP.  However, we have discovered a bug with memory pressure (msft currently looking at it) and need to move away from this implementation.

This table only contains ~300 records at any given time, and rarely do users WRITE to this table.  But there are hundreds of reads a second, potentially.

We're going to have to move back to a disk table for now, and I'd like to not log anything to the transaction log for reads on this table.  Is there a way to NOT log anything to the transaction log OR minimally log to the transaction log?

I looked into global temp table and also using TABLOCK and Minimally Logging keywords, but these all seem to be concerned only with high traffic WRITES.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want here?

Comment: As it stands this is a bit of an odd question and it's not clear what problem you're trying to solve. Are you looking for an on disk implementation that avoids lock contention? Latch contention? Something else? The transaction log shouldn't be an issue if the rate of changes is a single row is rarely written to the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> We're going to have to move back to a disk table for now, and I'd like to not log anything to the transaction log for reads on this table.

Reads aren't logged because they don't change anything, so you already get what you want.